# Should I create a corporation, even if I won't make money or receive funding until later?

Tags: small-business, limited-liability-company, corporation

Suppose I may not be profitable, make any money, or receive funding for another year. Should I still create the business entity now?

Comment: Which country you are referring to ?

Comment: If you don't make money or receive funding, then what *do* you do that might or might not require a company? If you tell us, we might then be able to tell you if incorporating would help with that or not.

Comment: @Philipp I'm making a software tool. I'd like for it to be eventually a profitable product from users who pay for features.

Comment: @trusktr Do you have any business expenses besides your own work time? Do you have any contractual obligations with 3rd parties as part of that project?